# Do Linux and Windows java compilers produce the same or different class files?

Tags: java, linux, windows, compilation

We have Java compilation both on Linux and Windows by the same version 1.6.0_25.

For some reason the resulted class files are different. Is it correct?

Comment: The files may be different on the byte level for several reasons. Yet they are identical as far as the JVM is concerned, i.e. you can run any class file, no matter where you compiled it as long as the compiling JDK is a compatible version.

Comment: The classfile format, the bytecodes, and the semantics of the language  are formally specified. While it's possible that you see some differences, if they produce different behaviour that's a compiler bug.

Comment: That is the question - about byte comparison.  It is not about running on different platforms.

Comment: Byte comparison doesn't really tell you anything. For instance, it doesn't matter what order you write the methods inside a class into a class file. So if you have a class `Foo()` with methods `bar()`, and `baz()`, one compiler run will first write out the bytecode for those methods in that order, the other compiler will do it in the opposite order. This could happen if, for instance, the compiler stores information about those methods in a hash map. (`hashCode()` is not guaranteed to return the same result for the same value between program invocations, and it's in fact better if it doesn't.)

Comment: Our goal is to determine the correspondence of the production war files and newest builds, so we use byte comparison by Beyond Compare

Comment: Time to upgrade to java 6 update 45 or java 7 update 40.

Answer (score 3):

The java compiler is not deterministic and may not generate the same .class if compiled on the same platform mulitple times or compiled on different platforms. I am trying to figure out the internals of java compiler to see why it is not deterministic.

Searching it further gives more insight while learning about cross compilation option in [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

**Cross-Compilation Options**

> **By default, classes are compiled against the bootstrap and extension
>   classes of the platform that javac shipped with**. But javac also
>   supports cross-compiling, where classes are compiled against a
>   bootstrap and extension classes of a different Java platform
>   implementation. It is important to use -bootclasspath and -extdirs
>   when cross-compiling; see Cross-Compilation Example below.

Comment: How this is related to our case: the same source files compiled on different platforms? Does compilation produce the same class files?

Comment: @anarinsky Forget about the option but check the bold part "By default, classes are compiled against the bootstrap and extension classes of the platform that javac shipped with."

Comment: @JunedAhsan I'm not sure that would lead to a difference at the byte-code level. The bootstrap classes are only referenced from your `.class` files by their name.

Comment: ... however the Java compiler is written in Java itself (at least older versions were) so the same compiler is used on both operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

Java bytecode is platform independent.

Comment: it is, but there are parts that can vary and still be an equivalent file.

Comment: Thank you, is the size the same or different?

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or the ones from Oracle? With the same options, flags and compiler version, the generated files would have same size.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786586/is-there-a-diffence-in-size-of-class-file-on-two-different-platforms